# Not being to get the footer being fixed at the bottom

Tags: html, css, footer

i am trying to fix a bug of the footer, as you can see the footer does not stay at the bottom of the browser like it should, it stays at the middle of the page if the page does not have enough content,  it just follows the height of the rest of the div's. Site Example: http://produccion.pugle.net/sarahbcn2/membership-cancelled/

So I tried to fix it with some css commands on the main div wrapper, like overflow:auto; or height:auto; and the same commands for the footer, but having no success. Any ideas of how solve this issue?
Thanx

Comment: Always place your code here instead of linking website...

Comment: Thanx for the tip, will do next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this decision will help you  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uwJjr)   [Sticky Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  <h1>Sticky Footer</h1>
  <h2>with Fixed Footer Height</h2>

  <button id="add">Add Content</button>  

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>


* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the help, but what actually solved the thing is putting the footer in a fixed position,  position: fixed;/*fixed position*/

Comment: Woops, just figurred this is the correct answer the other gets the footer stuck on the page no matter what, it become a problem when there is a lot of content since the footer always shows up even if there is content to scroll, so this answer was actually the one is was looking for thanx Alex, cause the footer shows up only when it has to and is fixed at the bottom not stuck no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Apply changes to your footer (use fixed position):

```
footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 center #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0 0;
    position: fixed;/*fixed position*/
    width: 100%;
}
```